# Python parser Module tutorial

Tags: python, parsing

I am writing an application which reads an input file that currently has its own grammar, which is processed by lex/yacc.

I'm looking to modify this so as to make this input file a Python script instead, and was wondering if someone can point me to a beginner's guide to using the parser module in Python.  I'm fairly new to Python itself, but have worked through a fair chunk of the online tutorial.

From what I have researched, I know there are options (such as pyparsing) which can allow me to keep the existing grammar and use Pyparsing as a replacement for lex/yacc. However, I am curious to learn the Python parser module in more detail and explore its feasibility.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You mean [the parser module](http://docs.python.org/library/parser.html)? It's a parser for Python source code only, not a general purpose parser. You can't use it to parse anything else.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to. I was thinking about having the input file to my application be a python file. So the grammar would be the python language, and this parser module would parse it. I was just wondering if there was a friendlier tutorial for this.

Comment: You might find the built-in ast module easier to use in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Can you recommend a beginner-level tutorial on using the AST module in Python? I've tried to search the web, but haven't seen anything concrete.

Answer (score 3):

As Jochen said, the parser module is for parsing Python code. I think you're best off checking out [Ned Batchelder's list of parsers](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html). PyParsing does things pretty differently from Lex and Yacc, so I'm not sure why you think you could keep your existing grammar and lexer. A better bet might be David Beazley's [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) toolkit. It's solid and has excellent documentation.

Comment: I'd like to get away from the lex/yacc way in general. I just saw your recommendation on the ast module and will try and find a friendly tutorial on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you check out https://github.com/erezsh/lark

It's great for newcomers to parsing: It can parse ALL context-free grammars, it automatically builds an AST (with line & column numbers), and it accepts the grammar in EBNF format, which is considered the standard and is very easy to write.